# Insert data to database SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert data to a database I have created. I have created an insert command at the OnCreate class. When viewing the database in SQLite Browser the data do not show. Can anyone help me

DatabaseHelper

```
package app.mobiledevicesecurity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
* Created by Martin on 2015/07/28.
*/
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mobilesec.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "read_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "CATEGORY";
public static final String COL_3 = "HEADING";
public static final String COL_4 = "INFO";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, CATEGORY TEXT, HEADING TEXT, INFO TEXT)");
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(COL_2,"Malware");
cv.put(COL_3,"Virus");
cv.put(COL_4,"Harmfull for device");
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
 package app.mobiledevicesecurity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
private static Button readbtn;
private static Button quizbtn;
private static Button scoresbtn;
private static Button settingsbtn;
private static Button helpbtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     OnClickReadButtonListener();
     OnClickQuizButtonListener();
     OnClickScoresButtonListener();
     OnClickSettingsButtonListener();
     OnClickHelpButtonListener();


}

public void OnClickReadButtonListener() {
    readbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readbutton);
    readbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new    Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Read_Category");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void OnClickQuizButtonListener() {
    quizbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quizbutton);
    quizbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Quiz");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void OnClickScoresButtonListener() {
    scoresbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scoresbutton);
    scoresbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Scores");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void OnClickSettingsButtonListener() {
    settingsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
    settingsbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Settings");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void OnClickHelpButtonListener() {
    helpbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.helpbutton);
    helpbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Help");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Check, is it correct make ID autoincrement, and after that set ID=1? Does your application any errors or messages?

Comment: Don't put the id in the insert command, since it it automatically generated.

Comment: when I run the app on the emulator and open Android Device Monitor and get the database file and open it with SQlite Browser. Only the Column names are created the values are not shown. Why is this happening

Comment: can anyone please help me. Why is the data not added to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declare ID as auto-increment, you should not insert values to that column. Try below code as your onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CATEGORY TEXT, HEADING TEXT, INFO TEXT)");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_2,"Malware");
    cv.put(COL_3,"Virus");
    cv.put(COL_4,"Harmfull for device");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe help me to write the Select query.                             Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME ,null); I want to add a where to this where COL_2 is equal to "Malware"

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert code like below..

```
 String ROW5 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + COL_2 + ", " 
                + COL_3 + ", " 
                + COL_4 + ") Values ('Malware', 'Virus', 'Harmfull for device')";
 db.execSQL(ROW5);
```

Comment: do not get anything still to show when I open the database in SQLite browser

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try like below code,to commit all *database* transaction after calling each sql statement.

```
    db.beginTransaction();//start transition for create table
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, CATEGORY TEXT, HEADING TEXT, INFO TEXT)");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
    db.endTransaction();//commit create table transaction
    db.beginTransaction();//start transition for insert data
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_2,"Malware");
    cv.put(COL_3,"Virus");
    cv.put(COL_4,"Harmfull for device");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
    db.endTransaction();//commit insert data transaction
```

Comment: do not get anything still to show when I open the database in SQLite browser